# What's the role of "de" in this expression?

Tags: grammaire

> un homme de cinquante ans plus jeune qu'elle

Je me demande si le "de" ici est strictement lié à l'age ou on peut l'utiliser aussi dans des autres contextes. Par exemple, est-ce correct ?

> C'est de 2 euros plus cher.

Et les mêmes phrases sans le "de", sont-elles correctes ?

> un homme cinquante ans plus jeune qu'elle

> C'est 2 euros plus cher.

Et si on ne donne pas un nombre spécifique, est-ce correct d'utiliser le "de" ?

> Je suis de beaucoup plus intelligent que toi.

Un autre aspect qui m'intéresse dans la phrase initiale, c'est l'ordre et s'il influence la nécessité d'utiliser le "de". Est-ce possible de réécrire la même phrase sans le "de", en utilisant autre ordre des mots ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- *Un homme cinquante ans plus jeune qu'elle.* (possible)
- *Un homme de cinquante ans plus jeune qu'elle.* (possible)
- *Un homme plus jeune qu'elle de cinquante ans.* (plus courant)
- *Un homme de cinquante ans de moins qu'elle.* (plus courant)

- *C'est de deux euros plus cher.* (rare, discutable)
- *C'est plus cher de deux euros.* (courant)
- *C'est deux euros plus cher.* (courant)

- *Je suis‎​, ​de beaucoup, plus intelligent que toi.* (grammaticalement correct mais prétentieux ;-)
- *Je suis plus intelligent que toi, de beaucoup.* (idem)

  Dans les deux phrases qui précèdent, ***de*** fait partie de la locution ***de beaucoup***. C'est un peu similaire pour ***de deux euros***.